# Object declaration in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a small doubt:

What is the difference between `str` and `str_obj` ; `cls` and `cls_obj`.

Are all of them are objects..??

(Got this doubt as they are declared in **different syntaxes**).

Can someone please elaborate ?

Thanks in advance.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Structure dayplan_str

        Public a As Integer
        Public b As String
        Public c As Boolean

    End Structure

    Public Class dayplan_cls
        Public a As Integer
        Public b As String
        Public c As Boolean
    End Class

    Public str As dayplan_str   'structure
    Public cls As dayplan_cls  'class
    Dim str_obj As dayplan_str = New dayplan_str  'structure
    Dim cls_obj As dayplan_cls = New dayplan_cls  'class


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        str.a = 5
        cls.a = 6
        str_obj.a = 7
        cls_obj.a = 8

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Seems, a structure and a class stores the same data types. Your doubt can be defined what is better or what to choose? See this: [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi @MaciejLos, Thanks for your comment, My doubt is the difference between the declarations...`Public cls As dayplan_cls` and `Dim cls_obj As dayplan_cls = New dayplan_cls`. Do they both represent the same..??

Comment: They refer to the same objects, but the difference is in their [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx). [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "cls" and "cls_obj" is in the way of declaration. They are all objects, but in "new cls_obj" the new object is also initialized. The difference is like in the following:

```
Dim k as long
Dim i as long
i = 0
```

In your case cls_obj is i.

Edit: Concerning the `public and dim` - the value declared with `dim` is only visible from the module, where it is declared. The value with `public` is visible in all modules.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for your answer. We does same in enums too as `Public Enum EXAMPLE As Integer
        wakeup = 1
        lunch = 2
        sleep = 3
    End Enum

    Dim EX As EXAMPLE` Does the EX is also object to ENUM..??

Comment: I did not understand completely the question, but I am quite positive the answer is "NO". Here is a good article for enums - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comments...@ Vityata

Comment: It is not exactly like the built-in types. A built-in type will be default-initialized to 0, whereas a class or struct type will not be default-initialized, causing you to get a NullReferenceException if you try to use it before it has been initialized.

Comment: That is true, @CodyGray. But still a close comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public str As dayplan_str   'structure
```

This is a declaration of a dayplan_str Object called str

```
Dim str_obj As dayplan_str = New dayplan_str  'structure
```

This is a declaration and initialization of a dayplan_str Object called str_obj

Comment: Hi, but in both the cases I am able to access its members.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public str As dayplan_str   'structure
```

This declares a variable named `str` that can hold a reference to an object of type `dayplan_str`. `dayplan-str` happens to be a structure, but it could also be a class.

The variable `str` has not been initialized. It currently does not hold a reference to any particular object. If you try to use the variable `str` in an expression, you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

---

```
Public str_obj As dayplan_str = New dayplan_str  'structure
```

This declares *and initializes* a variable named `str_obj`.

Like the previous declaration, it also declares a variable that can hold a reference to an object of type `dayplan_str`, but the second part of the statement (the part after the equal sign) *initializes* the variable by calling the `dayplan_str` structure's constructor and creating a new object.

If you use the variable `str_obj` in an expression, it will work fine (no `NullReferenceException`) because it has been initialized to point to a valid `dayplan_str` object.

Presumably, this is where the name comes from. The suffix `_obj` suggests that `str_obj` refers to an *actual object*, whereas `str` does not.

---

However, you can easily initialize `str` so that it does point to a valid object:

```
str = New dayplan_str
```

This has the same effect as the second form, it just spreads the declaration and initialization across two lines, instead of keeping it all in a single line.

Generally, you want to initialize variables at the point of their declaration, so the second (combined) form is to be preferred. You would only use this separated form if you had a particular reason that the variable needed to be declared before it could be meaningfully initialized.

---

There is another difference between the two declarations in your code, though, and that is one of *scope*. More specifically, it is a difference in the accessibility of the variables.

When you declare a class-level variable as `Public`, it is accessible from both inside of the class and outside of the class.

When you declare a class-level variable as `Private`, it is *only* accessible from inside of the class.

Variables in a class can also be declared `Friend`, `Protected`, and `Protected Friend`. Consult the documentation for more details on what those access specifiers mean.

The `Dim` keyword is very old, coming into VB.NET from the classical BASIC programming language. It just means "dimension" and is a generic way of declaring a variable. Because of its history, it does not have any intrinsic access specification. The accessibility of a variable declared with `Dim` in VB.NET depends on the context in which that variable is declared. When it is declared at class scope, as in your case, its accessibility will be private. So in that sense:

```
Dim str_obj As dayplan_str = New dayplan_str  'structure
```

is equivalent to:

```
Private str_obj As dayplan_str = New dayplan_str  'structure
```

which is another way that it is different from:

```
Public str_obj As dayplan_str = New dayplan_str  'structure
```